# Webpack.config.js file minify js and css. - How to minify js and css files when using webpack?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, webpack, minify

I just started to learn webpack, and I dont know how to minify all files (js and css). I know how to do it with gulp, but webpack...
So, my config file looks like this:

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')

    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

I really dont know how to minify, Ive read a lot of information but i didnt get what i want.

Comment: did you put the js and css files into assets folder and inported ? did you executed the command "yarn encore dev"

Comment: @hous yes yes i did

Comment: what you get in the console after "yarn encore dev" ?

Comment: well, i added to my config file this (after .setPublicPath and before module.export)
`
Encore.configureTerserPlugin((options) => {
   options.cache = true;
   options.parallel = true;
   options.terserOptions = {
   output: {
    comments: false,
  }
}
})
`
I get this "Compiled with 0 warnings" after yarn encore dev. But my css and js files still the same
@hous

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TerserPlugin

```
Encore.configureTerserPlugin((options) => {
   options.cache = true;
   options.parallel = true;
   options.terserOptions = {
   output: {
    comments: false,
  }
}
```